# verify sorting of list containing elements of type ["23d 12h 23m","13d 23h 3m","13d 21h 35m"] using python

Tags: python

I need to setup a method in `python` which will verify the sorting of list containing elements of type  `["23d 12h 23m","13d 23h 3m","13d 21h 35m"]`. I have sorted list from ui just need to verify the sorting. I did it by converting each element into hours.

```
def convert_timeleft_into_hours(self, time_left_list):

    for i in range(len(time_left_list)):

        days = str(time_left_list[i]).rsplit('d')[0]
        print days
        hours = str(time_left_list[i]).rsplit('h')[0]
        hours = str(hours).rsplit('d ')[1]
        print hours
        minutes = str(time_left_list[i]).rsplit('m')[0]
        minutes = str(minutes).rsplit('h ')[1]
        print minutes
        total_hours = (float(days)*24)+float(hours)+float(float(minutes)/60)
        print total_hours
```

Comment: good for you!  (what did you try?)

Comment: Hi. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Hint: Look at the `datetime` module. `datetime.timedelta(days=23, hours=12, minutes=23)` will give you a `timedelta` object that you can sort.

Comment: did it by converting each element into hours

Comment: def convert_timeleft_into_hours(self, time_left_list):
        for i in range(len(time_left_list)):
            days = str(time_left_list[i]).rsplit('d')[0]
            print days
            hours = str(time_left_list[i]).rsplit('h')[0]
            hours = str(hours).rsplit('d ')[1]
            print hours
            minutes = str(time_left_list[i]).rsplit('m')[0]
            minutes = str(minutes).rsplit('h ')[1]
            print minutes
            
            total_hours = (float(days)*24)+float(hours)+ 
            float(float(minutes)/60)
            print total_hours

Comment: @VarunGogia: Please put the code into your question by clicking the "edit" link (just below the "Python" tag). If you put it in a comment, you can't format it properly (which is a big deal for Python code since indentation is significant).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this, if I misunderstood your question please tell me.

```
a = ["23d 12h 23m","13d 23h 3m","13d 21h 35m"]
b = sorted(a)

if b == sorted(a):
    print("This is sorted")
else:
    print("This isn't sorted")
```

Comment: i have the list sorted in descending order from UI, need to verify that list is sorted descending